# Copy to Clipboard Button in a Calculated Column (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a Text field called **urlText** in a Document Library List. Everytime a document is created, a workflow populates this field with the URL of the Document. I want to make a calculated column/button that appears next to eachf item in a list that, when pushed, copies that document's URL to the clipboard. Is this possible to do?

Comment: This should be doable with some JavaScript.

Comment: Why a calculated column? Easiest way is to apply CSR with a JSLink and add a button to the title field that does: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/ You can stuff that in a Calculated Column, but a pain to develop/debug But why an extra urlText field? That info is available as HREF on the Title column

Comment: I want a button for each corresponding list item -- it seems like it would be easier as a calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some JavaScript from another question on Stack that copies one field. The question is asking how to copy multiple fields, but you can get what you want from the questions code. 
[Copying all the field's value of a list to other list using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153858/copying-all-the-fields-value-of-a-list-to-other-list-using-javascript)

Once you've got the value from the list fields, you can copy it to the clipboard like this Stack thread recommends. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: That answer copies field values to other items/lists, does not have any copy-to-clipboard code

Comment: Danny, using the resource you'd sent before, how would I point the js to identify a sharepoint column named "DocId" (internal name) and place the copy button next to it?